# Why does collapse not work In Laravel project?

Tags: php, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I am working through some examples from the tailwind css page.

https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/collapse/

https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/navigation/sidenav/

(looking at the collapsible examples on the sidenav).

Bottom line when I navigate to the page it shows everything already opened, and the buttons do nothing as far as collapsing or expanding.  I am running npm run watch and see it compiling so I do not think that is the issue.  What am I missing?

Here is my code (copied from the collapse example).  I think I have the same problem between the collapse and the navbar.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-8/12 bg-white p-10 rounded-lg mt-10">
            <a class="inline-block px-6 py-2.5 bg-blue-600 text-white font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase rounded shadow-md hover:bg-blue-700 hover:shadow-lg focus:bg-blue-700 focus:shadow-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-0 active:bg-blue-800 active:shadow-lg transition duration-150 ease-in-out" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseWithScrollbar" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseWithScrollbar">
              Longer content
            </a>
            <div class="collapse mt-4 max-h-24 overflow-y-auto" id="collapseWithScrollbar"  style="max-width: 500px">
              <p>
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente
                ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer
                farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them
                accusamus labore sustainable VHS. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor
                brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua
                put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
              </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have installed the javascript for this package?  You have the compiled javascript installed on the page?  Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: "I am working through some examples from the tailwind css page"
Don't confuse this library with the actual tailwind css

Comment: Hi @Snapey,  I followed the directions on how to install Tailwind for a Laravel project.   I don't know if that means I have installed the JS for the package or not.  Same thing with compiling.  I run npm run watch, and it does compile when I make changes/add components.

Comment: read the installation for this library of tailwind components  https://tailwind-elements.com/quick-start/  This is not just installing tailwind.  This library 'tailwind-elements' needs a javascript package to enable interactivity

Comment: Thank you Snapey.  This was the tip.  I read you're second comment and couldn't respond at the time but I went looking and noticed what you meant.  You were right tailwind-elements builds off tailwind css.  I followed the quickstart guide and got everything added in.  I then modified the app.js to require the tw-elements.  Seems to work perfectly now.  Thank you a lot.